Doubt about consuming
My friend drinks alcohol but I don't drink alcohol the next day he eat my half shawarma and I ate the remaining another half of the shawarma does it mean I drink or i ate alcohol
Does Allah forgive me if it is a sin

As long as there was no alcohol on the food, and your intention was not to have alcohol, then I don't think that is a sin, but Allah knows best.

Salaam,
By no means does this mean you drank alcohol. The shawarma was not cooked in alcohol, so you are fine. :) That said, the Quran clarifies that "intoxicants and games of chance" are "abominations of Satan's handiwork" (Soura 5:90-91). We interpret these verses as forbidding the use of intoxicants such as beer, wine and spirits. Since you do not drink, and you also did not intentionally consume alcohol, there is nothing to stress about. Always remember that Allah (swt) wishes ease for you, so don't stress! Hope that helps!
-MuslimGap
